# MX Subzone DNS Setup on xname.org

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, mx-record, dns-zone, zones

I've a zone example.tld configured with a wildcard CNAME (1&1), A records (custom & 1&1), MX records (1&1), and a subzone record (NS) pointing to ns1.xname.org.

I've configured the subzone subzone.example.tld conatining a MX record pointing to a NAS. I've added a sub-zone record (not sure if necessary)

However, when I dig to it using `dig @ns1.xname.org subzone.example.tld in mx`, I obtain MX records of example.tld.

How can I fix my configuration to have subzone MX records taken in account ?

I've tried `dig @ns1.xname.org subzone.example.tld in ns` with negative results :

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
subzone.example.tld.    86400   IN  CNAME   example.tld.
example.tld.    86400   IN  NS  ns2.xname.org.
example.tld.    86400   IN  NS  ns0.xname.org.
example.tld.    86400   IN  NS  ns1.xname.org.
```

Zone configuration (example.tld):

```
$TTL 86400 ; TTL par défaut
example.tld.        IN  SOA ns0.xname.org.  . (
                1234567891  ; numéro de série
                10800   ; Intervalle de rafraichissement
                3600    ; Intervalle de renouvellement de tentative
                604800  ; Délai d'expiration
                10800   ; TTL pour les réponses négatives
            )

$ORIGIN example.tld.
            IN      NS      ns1.xname.org.
            IN      NS      ns0.xname.org.
            IN      NS      ns2.xname.org.
        10  IN      MX  0   mx00.1and1.fr.
        10  IN      MX  1   mx01.1and1.fr.
example.tld.            IN      A       12.34.56.67




*           IN      CNAME       example.tld.


subzone         IN      NS      ns1.xname.org.
```

Subzone (subzone.example.tld)

```
$TTL 86400 ; TTL par défaut
subzone.example.tld.        IN  SOA ns0.xname.org.  . (
                1234567890  ; numéro de série
                10800   ; Intervalle de rafraichissement
                3600    ; Intervalle de renouvellement de tentative
                604800  ; Délai d'expiration
                10800   ; TTL pour les réponses négatives
            )

$ORIGIN subzone.example.tld.
            IN      NS      ns2.xname.org.
            IN      NS      ns0.xname.org.
            IN      NS      ns1.xname.org.
            IN      MX  0   mx.subzone.example.tld.
mx          IN      A       1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Does the NS record delegating the subdomain return when you query for that?

Comment: I've tried `dig @ns1.xname.org subzone.foo.tld in ns` with negative results (see. the updated question for details). The zone and sub zone are managed by the same NS (xname.org).

Comment: If only there were a domain name specifically reserved by IANA for examples. [Oh, wait.](http://www.iana.org/domains/example/)

Comment: XNAme itself  have long-time troubles with zone reload. **It** maybe source of your problem, check serial of parent

Comment: Checking the serial seemed to be the key. Serial returned by dig is not the one returned by xname when submitting the zone form.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to define your subdmain.  They way you are specifying requires you to specify the NS servers for the subdomain in the parent domain.

The alternate method is to just define it within the parent domain.

```
subdomain     IN MX   10  mx.subdomain.example.tld
mx.subdomain  IN A    192.0.2.4
```

or self MX

```
subdomain     IN MX   10  subdomain.example.tld
              IN A    192.0.2.4
```

or MX defined in parent domain

```
subdomain     IN MX   10  mx.example.tld
mx            IN A    192.0.2.4
```

The second method is commonly used when the subdomain refers to a host or service.  The first method us normally reserved when delegating a subdomain to a different DNS administrator and/or different name servers.

Comment: Don't mix hosts insidedomain and subdomains! Technically they are **different things**!

Comment: I could define the mx for the parent domain but this will override current settings for the domain. I would like if possible to keep the current mx on the parent domain. And override mx only for subdomain.

Comment: The original specification above will set the MX for the subdomain only.  I have added additional options as it appears this is a mail only subdomain.

Comment: Thanks for the edit (Upvoted your comment since I already upvoted answer), this is helpful though it does not apply to xname since the form does not allow specifying subdomain for MX records. I'll use the first spec with zone edit though.

Comment: If it is a mail only domain you can skip the MX record and just use an A record.  I used bind format so subdomain gets the address specified in the selfMX example.

Answer (score 1):

I added your zones (in their current state, after Joel Coel's edit) into my bind 9.7.3. It does return MX record:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;subzone.example.tld.       IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
subzone.example.tld.    86400   IN  MX  0 mx.subzone.foo.tld.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
subzone.example.tld.    86400   IN  NS  ns0.xname.org.
subzone.example.tld.    86400   IN  NS  ns1.xname.org.
subzone.example.tld.    86400   IN  NS  ns2.xname.org.
```

It seems that there's just some mistake, maybe your new zone file doesn't appear on the server yet, or there's some typo not shown here or it's a bug in their bind version or something like that.

I'm not sure though why you *need* such delegated subzone (like BillThor suggested).

Comment: I was notified by xname of the reload of my zones. I don't need delegated subzone. I need to have a MX configured for a subzone. I am currently using xname.org services. However, after checking, the serial is not up to date. Your assumption that the zone is not reloaded seems true.

Comment: so add the required "subzone in MX" instead "subzone in NS" and you are done. CNAME doesn't affects hostnames that have records of any kinds.

Comment: Not possible with the form provided by xname.org MX records always apply to the whole zone. I've switched to zoneedit, which reloads my records immediately, and allows setting the MX subzone like you advise.

Anyway, I now believe that there is no configuration problem, the zones are not updated despite misleading the mail received from xname.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see an MX record in the code that you provided, also MX records dont like CNAMES ...
so what you need to is :

subzone.example.tld.    86400   IN  **MX 10**   foo.tld.

Comment: The code I provided is a dig response not the zone configuration...

Comment: Moreover, the whole subzone seems skipped, not only MX.